# Plaid - Update mode not working showing ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED

Tags: plaid

I am new to plaid.
I created a plaid access_token and now its showing

"error_code":"ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED"

Using the doc I understand that we need to use update mode for solving this
then  access token will not change and no need to call token -exchange

after getting this error
I tried calling

```
https://sandbox.plaid.com/link/token/create
method -POST

{
  "client_id": "xxxxxx",
  "secret": "xxxxxx",
  "client_name": "test",
  "user": { "client_user_id": "xxxx" },
  "country_codes": ["US"],
  "language": "en",
  "access_token": "access-sandbox-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-111111"
}
```

then I got new link_token

```
{
    "expiration": "2021-11-09T13:46:12Z",
    "link_token": "link-sandbox-xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx",
    "request_id": "xxxxx"
}
```

Then after what I  need to do ?? .. I understand that no need to do token exchange  api.

but if I tried to use this api using the existing access-token it is showing the same error

```
https://sandbox.plaid.com/accounts/get
method -POST

{
  "client_id": "xxxxxx",
    "secret": "xxxxxx",
    "access_token": "access-sandbox-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-111111"
}
```

output

```
{
    "display_message": null,
    "error_code": "ITEM_LOGIN_REQUIRED",
    "error_message": "the login details of this item have changed (credentials, MFA, or required user action) and a user login is required to update this information. use Link's update mode to restore the item to a good state",
    "error_type": "ITEM_ERROR",
    "request_id": "3LMjpQHxYAMDwos",
    "suggested_action": null
}
```

in that document they are saying like this.
An Item's access_token does not change when using Link in update mode, so there is no need to repeat the exchange token process.

then why I am getting again this ??

What I need to do solve this issue?

```
// Initialize Link with the token parameter
// set to the generated link_token for the Item
const linkHandler = Plaid.create({
  token: 'GENERATED_LINK_TOKEN',
  onSuccess: (public_token, metadata) => {
    // You do not need to repeat the /item/public_token/exchange
    // process when a user uses Link in update mode.
    // The Item's access_token has not changed.
  },
  onExit: (err, metadata) => {
    // The user exited the Link flow.
    if (err != null) {
      // The user encountered a Plaid API error prior
      // to exiting.
    }
    // metadata contains the most recent API request ID and the
    // Link session ID. Storing this information is helpful
    // for support.
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting the Link token, you need to initialize Link with the Link token.  Per the docs:

"To use update mode for an Item, initialize Link with a link_token configured with the access_token for the Item that you wish to update."

https://plaid.com/docs/link/update-mode/

Once the user has successfully completed the Link flow, the access token should be reactivated.

Comment: I am following this doc.. In this doc there is a section  // Initialize Link with the token parameter ( attaching in the question) DO we need to run that code also ? If we need to run ,, we need to run from mobile side code.. Can we run this using go lang? I am using  "github.com/plaid/plaid-go/plaid"  in backend

Comment: Yes, you need to initialize Link with the Link token. The Link token is created on the backend, but that token needs to be passed to the frontend -- Link needs to be launched on the client side (mobile or web, whichever you are using). Link cannot be launched on the backend.